# LibGDX - Camera rotation

Tags: java, math, vector, libgdx, perspectivecamera

I'm trying to develop a 3D game and I'm having a problem with camera rotation because it uses Vector3 axis and an angle. I've tried searching the maths for it but I'm confused and I'm pretty slow too. My question is do i control rotation and is there way to make a pitch, yaw system to control player's camera ( like in Minecraft ) ? Also reference and links on where to start learning these things would be appreciated. Sorry if i broke any rules (kinda feel like this isnt programming related enough) or my terrible explanation

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow; questions asking for links to books, websites, and other resources are off-topic - please read the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. A quick Google search for *first-person camera implementation* yields many useful results (many of them in Unity). [Here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/19507/how-should-i-implement-a-first-person-camera) is an example implementation in C++ on a sister site.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and I know and I'm really sorry for breaking some rules but I'm really lost right now.

Comment: Check out the LibGDX forums for asking broad questions like this.

Comment: Since you are looking for something "like Minecraft" have you considered using `FirstPersonCameraController`? It's part of the LibGDX framework and should work right of the bat.

Comment: FPCC includes roll when rotating which i don't want

Answer (score 0):

simple camera system (like in minecraft) using xyz position, xy rotation.
glRotatef(rotx,1,0,0); **- head up/down**
glRotatef(rotY,0,1,0); **- head left/right**
glTranslated(-p.x,-p.y,-p.z); **- position**

imagine how at the very origin, the world is being rotated, then finally pushed away

if you was to move right, by perspective, the world is moving left.

Comment: This is a really helpful note, I will definitely keep this in mind as I'm a big idiot when it comes to geometry and stuff like this

Comment: you should watch this video ["How to program 3D graphics from scratch. Without 3D engines. (In Python) "](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g4E9iq0BixA) since it doesn't use matrices, it does these translations in reverse. moving the verts to you. then rotating left/right. then up/down. matrix math (like which is built into opengl) is just a little different. it's used since it's more efficient. but yeah, moving xyz, then rotY, rotX is the plain way to visualize it.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution

camera.rotate(Vector3.Y, deltaX) for pitch
camera.rotate(camera.direction.crs(Vector3.Y), deltaY) for yaw

use a temporary Vector3 object for the yaw rotation

Thanks for your response everybody